# How to configure JBOSS for HTTPS?

Tags: https, jboss, certificate

I am looking for a detailed guide to configure SSl in JBOSS 7. I am not using any front end server but only JBOSS. Can anybody guide me through the steps of generating a key from an authorised certificate and configuring the connector under jboss?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following procedure for self-signed certificate

1.Generate key + keystore

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias your_alias_here -keyalg RSA -keypass PASSWORD -storepass PASSWORD -keystore ENTER_KEYSTORE_NAME
```

2.Configure jboss for SSL ( file server.xml )

```
       <Connector port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="15"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
       keystoreFile="PATH_TO_KEYSTORE"
       keystorePass="PASSWORD" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

2.Import certs

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool  -import -v -alias your_alias_here -file FILE_YOU_RECEIVED_FROM_CA -keystore ENTER_KEYSTORE_NAME -storepass PASSWORD  -keypass PASSWORD
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, Do you know the procedure to generate a key using an authorised certificate?

Comment: You will need to generate a csr and submit it to the CA authority to get it signed. Once you receive the signed cert from the CA authority, you will need to import the certificate into the above keystore.

Comment: I guess my question would be, once I have a certified key , how to import the certificate into the keystore and will the next steps be same (configuring jboss config)?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have received a key and not a file from the CA , I want to be able to generate a file from this key. How to achieve that?

Comment: Private Key is what you generate using genkey (step 1). CA can only sign the cert for you.

Comment: I followed these steps following the modification needed for jboss 7. But I am not able to load the application on https interface. Are there any more configuaratons needed? There are no errors in the log.

Comment: Without looking at the configuration, its hard to say what the problem could be. How are you accessing the ssl site ? What happens when you type in the url ?

Comment: The certificate isnt being validated.

Comment: That may or may not be related to https. Try disabling ssl to make sure that the page renders correctly.

Comment: I want to be able to use ssl though